# while encoding I get potential leak of an object on CFBridgingRelease

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using the following code

```
+(NSString*)encodeString:(NSString*)p_string
{
    NSString* encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, CFBridgingRetain(p_string), NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

    return encodedString;
}
```

and with Analyse tool i get "Potential leak of an object"
1. Call to function 'CFBridgingRetain' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count
2. Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plainly bridge the incoming string: `(__bridge CFStringRef)(p_string)` instead of `CFBridgingRetain(p_string)`.